# Ruby code does not run on windows command line

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd

I tried to run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class StringSwap
  def initialize(str1,str2)
    raise Error unless str1.length>4
    raise Error unless str2.length>6
    temp=str1[3]
    str1[3]=str2[5]
    str2[5]=temp
    @str1=str1
    @str2=str2
  end
  def print()
    put str1
    put str2
  end
end

def main()
  puts "WHYYY"
  s1=gets().chomp()
  s2=gets().chomp()
  obj=StringSwap.new(s1,s2)
  obj.print()
end
```

Nothing happens when I type `ruby file.rb`. It does not give an error but it does not run my program either. When I tried to run scripts like "Hello World" in same way, it worked. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Remember in Ruby it's not necessary nor recommended to put in empty argument lists. That is, `s1=gets.chomp` is not only more concise, but it's more conventional in terms of Ruby style.

Comment: Not clear what help you want.

Comment: @sawa I was trying to run it as I specified and it did not work. I think I described the problem specifically. Anyway, it is solved. I am sorry if I could not describe it clearly.

Comment: You didn't specify anything about the way you wanted it to run.

Comment: @sawa I specified the way as windows command line by typing ruby -myfilename.rb and specified nothing happened in command line after I did that which is i figured out later because of there is a main method

Comment: You specified what you did, and what happened, but did not specify what you wanted to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to solve that by just deleting the main function. Then it worked but I don't know why? Could anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Your code defines a class and a method and then doesn't call or use either of them. Unlike C or Java, a method called `main` is not special.

Comment: Hello, I actually use StringSwap class to create an object. I did not understand when you said you don't call or use them. Also, is there a way to use main function in my code? Or what if I have more than one class, how should I compile that one though? Thanks @tadman

Comment: In Ruby there's the `main` *context*, that's basically the root level outside of classes or methods. Defining a method doesn't actually do anything. Calling a method does. Your solution to remove the `def main` part and promote the body of the method to the `main` level fixes the problem because it instructs Ruby to actually execute that code rather than define a method that may or may not be called later.

Comment: Don't ask questions in an answer. If you want to modify your question, then edit the question.